# Is there a way to allow temporary negative balances?

Tags: substrate-front-end, wallet

I would like to do two things;

1. On wallet generation, I would like to flag whether the wallet owner is corporate or consumer, AND
2. If corporate, allow balances to temporarily (~month) be negative

Very sorry for asking such a broad question, but if anyone could please help me look in the right direction.

Comment: I think that is impossible. But, what is your use case? I think there are other ways to do that. Why do you want negative balances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not store a negative balance on the storage. (I mean to use the `pallet-balances`, but you could write your own pallet.)

But there are other ways to make it looks like negative.

For example, you could add a lock on it.

`usable = free - lock`

If you set a big lock on this account. Then the usable balance is always `0`, unless `free > lock`.

And there are also a lot of ways to set a lock. I think you could start from the [`pallet-vesting`](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/vesting/README.md).

---

`total = reserved + free`

You could also use reserved to implement this feature. But IIUC, you might need to write some code in this way.

Comment: thanks very much for this. I will take a closer look and come back if any questions.